# pChart Radar chart with minimum 1

Tags: pchart

I'm using a Radar Chart similar to this example:
https://pchart.net/doc.draw.radar.html

My data ranges from score 1 to 4, so I configured some options:

```
$options = array(
    'SegmentHeight' => 1,
    'Segments' => 3,
    'FixedMax' => 4
);
```

One problem remains: Even if my lowest score is 1, the Radar chart always has the value 0 in the center.

How can I change the minimum value in the chart to 1?

Comment: What if you drop your lowest value? Then that would default to the center, correct?

Comment: I also thought that, but it doesn't work. The lowest value is 1 and still the radar shows the 0 value.

Comment: What if you subtract one from all your values, then your range would be 0-3. That would hopefully place your values in the center. Then you could change the labels to show 1-4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a "minimum" value, but only if you're willing to fork the library and make some changes.

## Game plan

The easiest and most straightforward way to do so is to create a new option that I'll call `FixedMin`. If, and only if, this new option is provided (and the other criteria for non-auto-segmentation are met) will you achieve the effect you're seeking.

If you want a minimum to be generated without providing `SegmentHeight`, `Segments`, and `FixedMax`, you'll also need to modify `pImage::computeScale` which generates these configuration values when they're not provided.

We need to make three changes:

1. Create a new configuration option called `FixedMin`
2. Adjust the values' position
3. Adjust the labels' text

## Let's code

The `drawRadar` method is held in `class/pRadar.class.php`. Open it up. Let's walk through our game plan.

**First**, let's add the configuration option. I'll add it with the others (line ~38) like so:

```
 $FixedMin      = isset($Format["FixedMin"]) ? $Format["FixedMin"] : 0;
```

Let's have `FixedMin` default to `0` because that is the default pChart behavior.

**Second**, we need to somehow trick pChart into repositioning these larger values as if they were smaller to accomodate the offset `FixedMin` creates.

We can do that where the function computes the plots position (line ~319). Find the loop `foreach($DataS["Data"] as $Key => $Value)` (line ~328). Here, we'll modify the `$Value` by adding this line at the top of the loop:

```
$Value -= $FixedMin; // Let's offset the perceived value by our new minimum
```

**Third**, we need to change the axis labels' text values. Inside the conditional that `$DrawAxisValues` encompasses, you'll find this line of code (line ~255):

```
$Label  = ($j * $SegmentHeight)
```

This works great; for each segment, it generates a label that is the segment times the height (e.g., 4 segments of 20 units should generate 4 labels with: 20, 40, 60, 80). But it won't work with our `FixedMin`. Let's reuse the offset. In this case, we're incrementing by the offset, to generate the illusion of a minimum. Replace that line with this one:

```
$Label  = ($j * $SegmentHeight) + $FixedMin;
```

## Recap

We created a new configuration variable for a minimum segment; and for each value, we subtracted that minimum value (or offset); and rejiggered the axis labels by adding that minimum value (or offset).

## Caveats

We only modified radar charts; no other chart type will be affected. Do *not* attempt to use data with values that are below the configured minimum. The hazards of doing so may be why the author didn't include this option.

## Show and tell

I don't have access to your data set, so I used the pChart example and bumped the "application review" sample so that all the scores were between 20 and 40.

```
// FixedMin set to 0, "default" behavior
$Options = array(
 'SegmentHeight' => 20,
 'Segments' => 2,
 'FixedMax' => 40,
 'FixedMin' => 0, // And so on...
```

[image: Default behavior]

As expected, now let's check out our new code...

```
// FixedMin set to 20, smaller SegmentHeight
$Options = array(
 'SegmentHeight' => 10,
 'Segments' => 2,
 'FixedMax' => 40,
 'FixedMin' => 20, // And so on...
```

[image: With a minimum of 20]

Ta-da.

Comment: I'm awarding you with the bounty for the research and proof of concept (before time runs out) and will accept the answer as soon as I implemented it. Thanks a lot, Jacob!